# Спряталось за горизонт или за горизонтом?

Tags: синтаксис

Как будет правильно? Я правильно понимаю, что допустимы оба варианта?

1. Оно спряталось за горизонтом.
2. Оно спряталось за горизонт.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Допустимы оба варианта.**

Справочник Розенталя "Управление в русском языке" отмечает два варианта согласования слова "Спрятаться":

> 1. куда (за что) (направление действия). Солнце точно играет в прятки: то спрячется за облако, то опять обольёт светом (Н.-П.); Пашка
>    спрятался за корзину с красными цветами (Пауст.).
> 2. где (за чем) (место действия). Сваакер... спрятался за стволом
>    соседней ветлы (Фед.); Мы придём заранее и спрячемся за сценой
>    (Нос.).